# AWS Cognito SDK missing user attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub, amazon-mobile-hub

I'm using AWS cognito and it's built-in UI in my Android App. I selected family name as required in AWS console but the field is not shown within the create new account form.
How can I add this field to the form.
Thank you.